# How to call a smart contract function multiple times but signing only once through phantom address

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I am trying to call the same smart contract function in a loop using web3/solana.
Currently I have to sign the transaction on every iteration. How do I make it so that I sign only once and the loop runs

Comment: you need to provide code to get a high quality answer. there are too many unknowns as presented

Answer (score 1):

you need to build a custom `Transaction` that calls the `program` multiple times. Calling that `transaction` will produce multiple `cpi` calls. But you have to keep in mind the `computation limit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on a web app, you might be looking for the `signAllTransactions` function: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/4c600d6763a02927c3c590d1a24fb62fa38758db/packages/core/react/src/useWallet.ts#L62

This is from the `@solana/wallet-adapter` package, specifically the export from `useWallet` hook.
This will allow the wallet (if it supports that) to sign multiple transactions at the same time.

However, it makes more sense to add multiple calls to your program within a single transaction if you can.